# Compile c++ to python using swig

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile very simple file to python on windows and I'm having a bad time.

The .i file is testfile.i:

```
%module testfile

%include "stl.i"

%{  
    int get_num() {
        return 3;
    }
%}  

int get_num() {
        return 3;
}
```

The swig function:
{swig path}\swig.exe -c++ -python testfile.i

This works perfectly, I now got the testfile.py file and testfile_wrap.cxx file.
Now I understood that I need to compile this to library (.pyd on windows). I tried:

{gcc path}\gcc.exe -fPIC -shared testfile_wrap.cxx -o testfile_wrap.pyd -L. -LC:\Python27\libs\ -lpython27 -IC:\python27\include.

Here is the problem, I get alot of errors like this ones:

```
C:\Users\itay\AppData\Local\Temp\ccANsNeU.o:testfile_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xc00): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_MemoryError'
C:\Users\itay\AppData\Local\Temp\ccANsNeU.o:testfile_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xc13): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IOError'
C:\Users\itay\AppData\Local\Temp\ccANsNeU.o:testfile_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xc26): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
C:\Users\itay\AppData\Local\Temp\ccANsNeU.o:testfile_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xc39): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
```

And it continues on and on.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Update:
I managed to call swig and compile/link using visual studio 2013 but I get the same error. I followed tutorials and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution: my python was 64 bit and it didn't work. Changed to python 32 bit and now it is working (python 2.7.10)

Comment: This will be because your gcc is compiling a 32 bit shared object, this is quite common on windows. There are 64 bit gcc versions available for windows if you're interested: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php

Comment: I actually tried it, same problem. And my visual studio is 64 bit too, weird